# lightning:buttonIcon on mobile is not working sometimes

Tags: aura, mobile, lightning-buttonicon

Currently working on an aura cmp that will also be present on mobile.

However, sometimes the button to refresh cmp to a certain state is not working on mobile. After a few tries it starts working but when it is tried from another phone it also stops working sometimes. What could be the cause of this? My code is below.

```
<div class="slds-truncate"  style="margin-right: 3px !important;" >
        <lightning:buttonIcon class="padclass" iconName="utility:refresh" alternativeText="Refresh Values" 
   title="Settings" onclick="{! c.refreshVal }" />
</div>

    init: function (cmp, event, helper) {
        var defaultdata = [{ vadeDate: new Date().toISOString(), vadeValue: ''},
        { vadeDate: new Date().toISOString(), vadeValue: ''},
        { vadeDate: new Date().toISOString(), vadeValue: ''}];
        cmp.set('v.defaultdata',defaultdata);
    },
    refreshVal: function (cmp, event, helper) {
        var defaultdata = cmp.get("v.defaultdata");
        cmp.set('v.data', defaultdata);
        cmp.set('v.isDisabled',false)
    },
```